# Is it possible to disconnect a WebDAV share in Windows 7?

Tags: webdav

I have an Apache server in my network with a WebDAV share using Digest Authentication. I also  used the "Add a network location" in Windows 7 to add the WebDAV share. The WebDAV share works without any problem so far.  Create, copy or delete files are working.

The first time I access the WebDAV share after I log on to Windows, I will enter my credential information (username and password).  I do not need to supply any credential information for the 2nd and 3rd time I access the WebDAV if I don't log out from Windows 7.

Is there any easy way to log me out or disconnect my WebDAV share after I finish using the share but not log out from Windows 7?

The WebDAV share contains important and sensitive data and I wish to end the session once I finish my task again the share.  A function like disconnect would be sufficient for me.

Answer (score 7):

To disconnect WebDAV share use the 'net use' command. For example to disconnect all shares run in a command prompt:

```
net use * /delete
```

You may also want to clear the cached credentials. In this case you can run in a command prompt:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

This command will display a dialog in which you can delete cached login/password.

Comment: Deleting *all* the used shares on a device is probably not an ideal solution. It would be more helpful to explain how the specific share can be deleted.

Comment: Instead of `rundll32`, I open Control Panel -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 8.1, the following approach worked for me:

1)  Go to the Services Console (services.msc)

2)  Find the running Webclient service and then Stop it

3) Refresh the Network Locations Window and then the WebDav location should be gone

4) Restart the Webclient service.

Answer (score 1):

You put your mouse pointer over the connection (in Windows Explorer), click the right button mouse and choose **Delete**

Comment: Once delete will I lost the link?  I have to re-build next time to connect the the service.